# mongoose allowDiskUse(true) not working nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following code:

```
pastlocation.aggregate([
        {
          '$project': {
            'location': 1, 
            'month': {
              '$month': '$timestamp'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$match': {
            'month': 11
          }
        },{
          '$group': {
            '_id': '$location.coordinates', 
            'count': {
              '$sum': 1
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$project': {
            '_id': 0, 
            'count': 1, 
            'location.coordinates': {
              '$map': {
                'input': '$_id', 
                'in': {
                  '$toString': '$$this'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },{$sort:{count:-1}}
      ]).allowDiskUse(true).exec(function(err,result) {

        if(err){console.log(err)}
     
      console.log(result)
      res.json(result);
      
  });
```

From everything I read this is the correct way to do allowDiskUse when using Mongoose with version 5.11.8

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-allowDiskUse

However I seem to get this error message.

```
MongoError: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/AdStichr-Server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/AdStichr-Server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/russellharrower/Documents/NodeApps/AdStichr-Server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:716:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1609147254 },
  ok: 0,
  code: 16819,
  codeName: 'Location16819',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1609147254 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  }
}
```

I am using MongoDB Atlas - is there a setting I need to turn on or have a missed something?

Comment: It seems that it's working but the problem in the pipeline stages depending on indexes and the size of data.
I suggest checking indexes on the fields that you are matching and sorting and try to reduce the pipelines. you may use match directly and remove the first projection pipeline if you can.

Comment: @MohamedKamel thanks for your comment - you mean put the date portion in the main project and remove the top one.

the issue is this collection has over 600,000 documents.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sort buffer size:

```
db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, "internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes" : 1 } )
```

( By default for mongod is 32MB , but it seems for ATLAS is 100MB)
You can try increasing it for example to 300MB :

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 314572800})
```

also not sure about your schema , but maybe $match stage could be moved before $project , and $project to allow only location.coordinates for the above case ...